# Настроить 301 редирект в .htaccess

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Помогите настроить редирект с:

```
site.ru/category/product/?brand=146&page=1
```

на:

```
site.ru/category/product/?brand=146
```

Требуется убрать "page=1", чтобы не возникало продублированной страницы.
В .htaccess прописано правило:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Оно убирает "page=1" в такой ситуации:

```
site.ru/category/product/?page=1
site.ru/category/product/
```

Для "brand" это правило не подходит.
Не могу понять, как в RewriteRule прописывается адрес, на который происходит редирект. В RewriteCond удавалось настроить условие, но вот перевести на корректную страницу не получилось.

С уважением, Олег.

Comment: "brand=146", не только 146, таких страниц несколько.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее, вот так должно заработать:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?page=1(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Сегодня уже не смогу ответить, в понедельник проверю и напишу. Благодарю!

Comment: @Живой, я изначально неправильно понял задачу. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Слеш один оказался лишним:
site.ru/category/product/?brand=146&page=1

редирект на:

`site.ru/category/product//?brand=146`

Исправился так:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?page=1(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]`