# Редирект htaccess

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Как сделать редирект со страницы:

```
mydomen.ru/subfolder1/subfolder2/zamena-displeja?width=500&height=280&inline=true
```

На страницу:

```
mydomen.ru/subfolder1/subfolder2/zamena-displeja
```

Comment: `Redirect /subfolder1/subfolder2/zamena-displeja?width=500&height=280&inline=true http://mydomen.ru/subfolder1/subfolder2/zamena-displeja`

Comment: не, так точно не работает. здесь же гет параметры

Comment: Ну тогда попробуйте так: `<If "%{QUERY_STRING} == '?width=500&height=280&inline=true'"> Redirect /subfolder1/subfolder2 /subfolder1/subfolder2/zamena-displeja </If>`

Comment: а вообще, вы бы взялянули б на подобные вопросы. Вот [в этом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/355701/183314), например, также пытаются убрать лишние GET-параметры из запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь функцией PHP:

```
function md_redirect(){
    $domain = 'https://mobidevices.ru';
    if('https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== $domain.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
        header('Location: '.$domain.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],true,301); exit;
    }
}
```

Она сравнивает ссылку страницы со ссылкой в адресной строке и если она ей не соответствует, то редиректит на нормальный адрес.