# .htaccess 301 редирект со страницы catalogN/page-1/ на страницу catalogN

Tags: .htaccess

Пожалуйста, помогите настроить 301 перенаправление со страницы каталога
`catalogN/page-1/` на страницу `catalogN`

Я нашел здесь подобный вопрос, но [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/355709/183314) мне не совсем подошло.

Comment: На данном ресурсе вопросы принято задавать на русском языке.

Comment: В общем нашел ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880975/htaccess-rewrite-first-page-of-pagination-to-original-url) RewriteRule ^(.*)/page-1 /$1 [L,R]

Comment: это правило вам переделает все ссылки вида `/one/two//page-1` на `one/two`, а не только `catalogN`